Power spectrum scaling conventions
Continuous and discrete Fourier transform has a number of scaling conventions. The same applies to power spectrum. In one of the articles posted on DSPrelated.com website on power spectrum measurement, the authors uses the $N^2$ division convention Link. The demonstration code was specifically for MATLAB. MATLAB does not scale the raw fft output by N. Starting from the Parsavel's theorem:
$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |x(n)|^2 = \frac1N\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|X(k)|^2$
the author divided both sides by $N$
$\frac1N\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |x(n)|^2 = \frac1{N^2}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|X(k)|^2$
and then states that
$P_{bin}(k)= \frac1{N^2}|X(k)|^2, \quad{k=0:N-1}  \}$
Several authors divide the squared absolute value of the discrete Fourier transform values by $N$ not by $N^2$.
Which convention is mathematically more rigorous (if we could say that), that actually represents the correctly scaled version of power in a signal? Division by $N$ or $N^2$ especially in MATLAB?

$N^2$ is correct (if there is no windowing).
Please see this answer. For details, this reference is in my opinion the best on the subject.

@Jdip Thanks for the useful chapter.

$\frac{1}{N}$ scaling satisfies Parseval's theorem. If you assume the PSD output is constant over the bandwidth of each DFT filter, then the power becomes a rectangular multiplication (the PSD multiplied by the bandwidth). In this case, the bandwidth of one of the DFT filters is inversely proportional to it's length. So, for a length $N$ filter, you have a $\frac{1}{N}$ bandwidth, giving the $N^{2}$ in the denominator.

@Baddioes I think that qualifies as an answer!

@Jdip alright, I'll write something up

The scaling of $\frac{1}{N}$ satisfies Parseval's theorem. The proof is pretty straightforward. We wish to show
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \lvert x[n] \rvert^{2} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \lvert X[k] \rvert^{2}
\end{equation}
We can then say
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \lvert X[k] \rvert^{2} &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}x[m]e^{-j2\pi\frac{km}{N}}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x^{*}[l]e^{j2\pi\frac{kl}{N}} \\ &= \sum_{m=0}^{N-1}x[m]\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x^{*}[l]\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{j2\pi\frac{(l-m)k}{N}}
\end{align}
The last term is a geometric series that is equal to
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{j2\pi\frac{(m-l)k}{N}} &= \frac{1 - e^{j2\pi(l-m)}}{1-e^{j2\pi\frac{(l-m)}{N}}} \\ &= \delta_{l,m}
\end{align}
Thus, computing
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{j2\pi\frac{(m-l)k}{N}} = N\delta_{l,m}
\end{equation}
Plugging this back in we get
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\lvert X[k] \rvert^{2} &= N\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}x[m]x^{*}[m] \\ &= N\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\lvert x[m] \rvert^{2}
\end{align}
Parseval's theorem is very closely related to the periodogram estimate of the power spectral density (PSD). The power spectral density is defined as
\begin{equation}
\phi(\omega) = \lim_{N\to\infty}E\{\frac{1}{N}\lvert\sum_{t=0}^{N}y(t)e^{-j\omega t}\rvert^{2}\}
\end{equation}
The periodogram simply drops the expected value to give (in the discrete case)
\begin{equation}
\phi[k] = \frac{1}{N}\lvert\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}}\rvert^{2}
\end{equation}
The $\frac{1}{N^{2}}$ comes into play with something called the power spectrum. There is much confusion over the difference between the two. The power spectrum (PS) $S$ is related to the PSD by
\begin{equation}
S(\omega_{1-2}) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\omega_{1}}^{\omega_{2}}\phi(\theta)d\theta
\end{equation}
What this means is that the PSD gives the average power (note the expected value in the definition) in the signal at frequency $\omega$, the PS accumulates the average power over a finite bandwidth to give the band-limited power. In the discrete world, there is no continuous spectrum, so the PSD accumulates the power from a small bandwidth and then normalizes by the bandwidth to estimate the average power at the center frequency $2\pi\frac{k}{N}$. The PS undoes this normalization. For a digital filter with temporal aperture $N$, the bandwidth $\beta$ is roughly $\frac{1}{N}$. So, we have
\begin{equation}
S[k] = \beta\phi[k] = \frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{N}\lvert X[k]\rvert^{2} = \frac{1}{N^{2}}\lvert X[k]\rvert^{2}
\end{equation}
If there is windowing or overlapping, this will affect the bandwidth of the filter and requires an alternate scaling, which the reference mentioned by @Jdip in the comments gives. It's also important to note that a one-size-fits-all scaling doesn't apply to adaptive-bandwidth or parametric spectral estimators.
The PS, in my opinion, is also not best represented as a "spectrum" (it's not really a continuous function), but that's a discussion for another time, as in the discrete world it's really just splitting hairs.
EDIT: Updated the geometric series formula, which was wrong. Jeeahmuhtry hard. It should be the correct formula now.

Thank you Baddioes, I was interested in scaling power spectrum not power spectrum density, so in power spectrum 1/$N^2$, scaling is correct, provided there is no window.

@ACR provided there is no windowing or overlap, yes.

What did you mean by overlap in a power spectrum?

@ACR overlap refers to something live Welch's method, where the data is broken up into smaller chunks, you take the magnitude squared of the DFT of each chunk, and then average. The temporal aperture of each chunk is smaller than the whole aperture, making the bandwidth of each DFT filter larger, requiring a different scaling.

Okay, right. Welch is another story compared to the simple power spectrum.

@ACR if the answer I provided is sufficient, can you please accept it so that it will be marked as completed for the site.
