Total band power, frequency resolution, and spectrum analyzer
For context, I would like to calculate total noise power of an intrument over a certain frequency band (e.g.,10Hz to 2MHz) using a spectrum analyzer. But, I came to know that total noise power would depend on the frequency resolution of the frequency sweep (using fft). I will get a different total noise if I use a frequency resolution of 10Hz vs 100Hz. My question is- which one is the true representation total noise of my instrument then?

See this answer https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/94663/power-spectrum-scaling-conventions/94665#94665 . Multiply by the appropriate scaling and sum over the bandwidth of interest.

Th easiest way to get the power is in the time domain. If you sample your signal without aliasing, the signal power is simply
$$P = \frac{1}{N}\sum x^2[n] \tag{1} $$
This represents the total power from DC to the Nyquist frequency. If you want less bandwidth, you need to apply a commensurate bandpass filter first.
If you want to use a DFT in the frequency domain, I suggest using symmetric DFT scaling, i.e.
$$X[k] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}}\\
 x[n] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k]e^{+j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}}$$
This preserves Parseval's Theorem and the total power becomes independent of the frequency resolution.
$$ \sum x^2[n] = \sum |X[k]|^2 $$
